# "Is idle" or "Is idling"

Tags: tenses, present-tense

I'm working on an app which displays status messages, like:

- "XY is now available"
- "XY is now offline"

I'm wondering which of the followings is correct:

- "XY is now idle"
- "XY is now idling"

Comment: cf. **1. A state of idling.** Used of a motor vehicle: an engine running quietly at idle. **2. A mechanism for regulating the speed at which an engine runs at rest:** set the idle higher to keep the motor from stalling. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idling

Comment: It depends on what it does while idle/ idling. Does it monitor activity? Does it ping for user input?

Comment: In this context, I mean when a user is logged in, but no interaction made with the application for a while.

Comment: Interaction with the application is user-activity. Does the app do anything, such as run a elapsed time clock say, or does the user invoke the app by themselves?

Comment: The app runs an internal timer. If the user doesn't interact with the application for a given period (tap on the screen, etc.) it will toggle the status to idle. People who are subscribed for this user will get a push notification like: "XY is now idle/idling".

Comment: No, my question was whether it does anything **while in the state of 'idle'** -- like how long it has been idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [clarification that this is in reference to the user](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175716/is-idle-or-is-idling#comment367218_175716), I am not sure that either of "idle" or "idling" is ideal.

I think that the general meaning of being "idle" is rather along the lines of not having been put to work, and "idling" could be rolling your thumbs or some other pointless activity for passing time.

I don't think that it's necessarily appropriate to refer to these inactive users as either "idle" or "idling", unless perhaps this application is actually supposed to keep them busy by handing out work orders or something like that.

It is recognized IRC jargon to refer to inactive users as "idle" but I think that comes from mixing the concept of the actual user with the concept of their client software.

Maybe simply referring to these users as "inactive" would be better?

Answer (score 1):

In programing terms, a program or it's activity goes **Idle**. In this field we don't use **idling** as an act of processing or setting actions (crunching numbers or using CPU power which is the opposite of being in the idle state) to achieve an idle state.

So **idle** is a state not an action in this context and a thread alpha, job A, process B or worker XY is now idle.

### Update

As oppose to idling, we use **Stabilizing** or **Optimizing** which carries the meaning of, some worker is doing an action which consumes resources to achieve a more stable state for a self or third party process.

Comment: Note that *stable* and *stabilizing* mean different things, as do *optimal* and *optimizing*.